# Bootstrap prevents form from submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the [startbootstrap-clean-blog-1.0.2](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/clean-blog/) template as a base for my general project. I am currently making a small list/view application (My first try at such a thing). When i click the 'submit button' in my form, bootstaps validation script for the contact form runs and prevents the form from submitting due to 'indexof' conflicts/errors (if i am guessing correctly)

Using Chromes developer tools I found the following error when I click the submit button:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined 
(Clean-blog.js:25)

$.jqBootstrapValidation.submitSuccess 
(Clean-blog.js:25)

(anonymous function)
Clean-blog.js:25

jquery.js:4409 jQuery.event.dispatch
(jquery.js:4095) 

jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle
(jquery.js:4095)
```

I've no real understanding of javascript or jQuery, still learning PHP. The errors seem to have something to do with a validation script for the contact form WHICH my list/View page has nothing to with (or so i thought). All I am trying to do is make sure that my form works (When I click the button, it goes to the submitted.php page). How can I get the page to submit?

I've seen many posts asking 'how to prevent a submit' but nothing on how to get a form in bootstrap to submit' on stack.

This is my code:

```
<form class='' action='sent.php' method='post' name='sendTest'>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <h2>TEST</h2>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for='name'>Name:</label>
                            <input type='text' name='name' />
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <button type='submit'>Insert Name</button>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [clean-blog](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mikescops/Clean-Blog/master/js/clean-blog.js) expects an input element with id `name`(`var name = $("input#name").val()`) which is not there in your code

```
<input type='text' name='name' id="name"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the code from [Clean-blog.js](https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-clean-blog/blob/gh-pages/js/clean-blog.js) you could check that is trying to access the value of the input by id, using `$("input#name").val()` but you are only defining the `name="name"`.

Code in the js:

```
var name = $("input#name").val();
var email = $("input#email").val();
var phone = $("input#phone").val();
var message = $("textarea#message").val();
var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
// Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
    firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
}
```

But the selector results in `firstName` undefined, so could not perform the indexOf.

Add `id="name"` for your input:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
```

Comment: Am i to add that to the .JS or the .php or both?

Comment: Just include the id="name" to your input field in your php.